# MOEA/D Algorithm Always Returning a Single Solution Instead of the Pareto Frontier

Tags: python, debugging, optimization, evolutionary-algorithm

```
class MOEAD:
    def __init__(
        self, 
        problem, 
        n_dim, 
        n_population, 
        n_neighbors, 
        bounds, 
        n_generations, 
        crossover_probability, 
        mutation_probability, 
        crossover_distribution_index, 
        mutation_distribution_index
    ):
        
        self.problem = problem
        self.n_dim = n_dim
        self.n_population = n_population
        self.n_neighbors = n_neighbors
        self.bounds = bounds
        self.n_generations = n_generations
        self.crossover_probability = crossover_probability
        self.mutation_probability = mutation_probability
        self.crossover_distribution_index = crossover_distribution_index
        self.mutation_distribution_index = mutation_distribution_index
        
        self.population = None
        self.weights = []
        self.neighbors = None
        self.EP = []
        self.history = []

    def initialize(self):
        self.population = np.random.uniform(self.bounds[0], self.bounds[1], (self.n_population, self.n_dim))
        self.weights = np.array([np.array([i / (self.n_population - 1), 1 - i / (self.n_population - 1)]) 
                                 for i in range(self.n_population)])
        distances = np.linalg.norm(self.weights[:, np.newaxis, :] - self.weights, axis=2)
        self.neighbors = np.argsort(distances, axis=1)[:,1:self.n_neighbors+1]

    def evolve(self):
        for gen in range(self.n_generations):
            for i in range(self.n_population):
                parents = np.random.choice(self.neighbors[i], 2, replace=False)

                child1, child2 = self.sbx_crossover(self.population[parents[0]], self.population[parents[1]])
                
                child1 = self.polynomial_mutation(child1)
                child2 = self.polynomial_mutation(child2)

                self.update_population_and_EP(child1, i)

                self.update_population_and_EP(child2, i)
                        
            self.history.append(self.EP.copy())

    def sbx_crossover(self, parent1, parent2):
        eta = self.crossover_distribution_index
        rand = np.random.random(size = parent1.shape)
        beta = np.empty_like(rand)
        beta[rand <= 0.5] = (2 * rand[rand <= 0.5]) ** (1 / (eta + 1))
        beta[rand > 0.5] = (2 * (1 - rand[rand > 0.5])) ** (-1 / (eta + 1))

        child1 = 0.5 * ((1 + beta) * parent1 + (1 - beta) * parent2)
        child2 = 0.5 * ((1 - beta) * parent1 + (1 + beta) * parent2)
        
        child1 = np.clip(child1, self.bounds[0], self.bounds[1])
        child2 = np.clip(child2, self.bounds[0], self.bounds[1])

        do_crossover = np.random.rand() < self.crossover_probability
        return (child1, child2) if do_crossover else (parent1, parent2)

    def polynomial_mutation(self, individual):
        eta = self.mutation_distribution_index
        for i in range(self.n_dim):
            if np.random.rand() < self.mutation_probability:
                delta = np.random.rand()
                if delta < 0.5:
                    multiplier = (2 * delta)**(1 / (eta + 1)) - 1
                else:
                    multiplier = 1 - (2 * (1 - delta))**(1 / (eta + 1))
                individual[i] += multiplier * (self.bounds[1] - self.bounds[0])
        individual = np.clip(individual, self.bounds[0], self.bounds[1])
        return individual

    def update_population_and_EP(self, child, i):
        child_obj = self.problem.evaluate(child)
        for j in self.neighbors[i]:
            weighted_sum_child = np.dot(self.weights[j], child_obj)
            weighted_sum_current = np.dot(self.weights[j], self.problem.evaluate(self.population[j]))
            if weighted_sum_child < weighted_sum_current:
                self.population[j] = child

        # Cập nhật quần thể mở rộng (EP)
        is_dominated = False
        for other_obj in self.EP:
            if np.all(other_obj <= child_obj) and np.any(other_obj < child_obj):
                is_dominated = True
                break
        if not is_dominated:
            self.EP = [other_obj for other_obj in self.EP if not (np.all(child_obj <= other_obj) and np.any(child_obj < other_obj))]
            self.EP.append(child_obj)

    def run(self):
        self.initialize()
        self.evolve()
        return self.EP, self.history
```

I've been working with the MOEA/D (Multi-Objective Evolutionary Algorithm based on Decomposition) algorithm, and I've encountered an issue. Regardless of the parameter settings I've tried, such as changing the weighting scheme, population size, or the number of neighboring subproblems, the algorithm consistently returns only a single solution instead of the expected Pareto frontier.

I've thoroughly reviewed my implementation and tried various combinations of parameters, but I can't seem to get the algorithm to produce the desired Pareto front. I suspect there might be a bug or an issue in my code, but I'm having trouble pinpointing it.

Could anyone provide some guidance on how to debug this issue or offer insights into common pitfalls when using MOEA/D? I would greatly appreciate any assistance or suggestions.

**Initialization:**

- Create Initial Population: Generate a population of N random
  solutions.
- Assign Weights: Assign a set of $$N$$ weight vectors
  corresponding to each individual
  $$\left{\left(\frac{i}{N-1},1-\frac{i}{N-1}\right):i=\overline{0,N-1}\right}$$.
- Set Neighborhood Parameters: Determine the number of neighbors $T$
  for each weight vector $i$, where the neighbors of vector $i$ are
  denoted by set $B(i)$ and consist of $T$ vectors with the smallest
  Euclidean distance to it.
- Initialize the External Population:
  Initialize the external population of Pareto solutions, $EP =
  \emptyset$. Evaluate the Population:

  Compute the objective function values for each solution in the
  population.

**Main Loop:**

In each generation, iterate over each individual. For each individual $i\in{1,2,\ldots,N}$, perform the following steps:

- Randomly select 2 individuals $x^k$ and $x^l$ from $B(i)$ and apply
  crossover (SBX) and mutation (Polynomial) operations to create an
  individual $x^*$.
- For each $j \in B(i)$, if the total weight (according to vector $j$)
  of $x^$ is less than the total weight of $x^j$, replace $x^j$ with
  $x^$ and compute the objective function values at $x^*$.
- Remove all solutions in $EP$ that are dominated by $x^*$.
- Add $x^$ to $EP$ if there are no solutions in $EP$ that dominate
  $x^$.

Continue iterating through generations until a stopping criterion is met, then return the set of solutions in $EP$.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regardless of the parameter settings I've tried, such as changing the weighting scheme, population size, or the number of neighboring subproblems, the algorithm consistently returns only a single solution instead of the expected Pareto frontier.